# Symfony 2 bin/vendors: "fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository" on remote machine, fine on local

Tags: git, symfony

```
bin/vendors install
```

works on my local machine. However, three entries in my deps file fail with the following messages when I run "bin/vendors install" on my remote testing machine:

```
> Installing/Updating aws-sdk-for-php
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> Installing/Updating AmazonWebServicesBundle
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> Installing/Updating Imagine
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

The rest of the entries in deps work fine on both machines. Here is my deps file:

```
[symfony]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=v2.0.11

[twig]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
    version=v1.6.0

[monolog]
    git=http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog.git
    version=1.0.2

[doctrine-common]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.1.4

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.6

[doctrine]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.6

[swiftmailer]
    git=http://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git
    version=v4.1.5

[assetic]
    git=http://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git
    version=v1.0.2

[twig-extensions]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions.git

[metadata]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata.git
    version=1.0.0

[SensioFrameworkExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[JMSSecurityExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
    version=origin/1.0.x

[SensioDistributionBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[SensioGeneratorBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[AsseticBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
    version=v1.0.1

[aws-sdk-for-php]
    git=http://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php.git

[AmazonWebServicesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/Cybernox/AmazonWebServicesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Cybernox/AmazonWebServicesBundle

[Imagine]
    git=http://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine.git
    target=imagine
```

I appreciate any help! I don't know where to start with this one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bin/vendors install --reinstall
```

fixed my problem.

"--reinstall" is necessary the first time you run it in a given repository, otherwise the remote libraries will not be cloned into your project. See my comment above, and symfony docs:

"When you execute the php bin/vendors install, for every library, the script first checks if the install directory exists. If it does not (and ONLY if it does not), it runs a git clone."

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html#managing-vendor-libraries-with-bin-vendors-and-deps

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case that the repositories you have problems with are already on disk on your remote machine (cloning should work since they do exist on github) but their "origin" is set to a repo that doesn't exist.

Open up aws-sdk-for-php/.git/config and make sure that its url is the same as the one in the deps file, e.g. url below should be

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = ..
        url = http://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php.git
```

Comment: My aws-sdk-for-php dir on the remote is completely empty. If this helps, I added all 3 problem libs/bundles (aws, aws bundle and Imagine) on the local machine, pushed my changes to a barebones repo on the remote machine, pulled the updates into my working dir on the remote machine, and then tried bin/vendors install.  All 3 problem libs/bundles in the remote working dir are now empty directories with no .git or anything else.

Comment: I just got it working with `bin/vendors install --reinstall`. I think the reinstall is needed because the remote libraries had never been cloned on the remote machine. I found this in the Symfony docs: 

"When you execute the php bin/vendors install, for every library, the script first checks if the install directory exists.

If it does not (and ONLY if it does not), it runs a git clone."
[link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html#managing-vendor-libraries-with-bin-vendors-and-deps)